# Uninitialized Condition Valgrind

Tags: c, initialization, structure, valgrind

After running the following C program with Valgrind, it says the `packets.payload` variable is uninitialised. But I cannot figure out why since I've already put "1234567890" in `packets.payload`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct packet {
    int payload_length;
    char payload[10];
} packet_t;


int main () {
    packet_t packet;
    strncpy(packet.payload, "1234567890", 10);
    puts(packet.payload);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer to *a string* (a sequence of characters *terminated by null-character*) must be passed to `puts()`.

Your `packet.payload` doesn't contain terminating null-character, so you cannot use it for `puts()`.

You can use `printf()` with specifying length to print to print that:

```
printf("%.*s\n", 10, packet.payload);
```

Answer (score 1):

`packet_t packet ={0, "0000000"}` is initialization. In the code, you are just assigning the value, not initialization.  Initialization of a variable provides its initial value at the time of construction (definition).